# Unexpected character (ï) at position 0. JSON parsing with java using sample-json-1.1.1

Tags: json

I am trying to parse Har file, generated from ie11 browser using sample-json in java and i am getting "Unexpected character (ï) at position 0" 
And the same code is working fine for Har file generated from chrome browser.

Below is the code i am using.

```
JSONParser jsoneParser = new JSONParser();
Object object ;
JSONObject  jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsoneParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("jsonfile.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Output:
    Unexpected character (?) at position 0.
        at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
        at jsontojava.jsonreader.main(jsonreader.java:74)



Can some one pleases help with correct solution for this
```

Comment: Looks like the HAR file you're trying to parse is not valid JSON. Have you verified that the file contains valid JSON?

Comment: yes it is a valid json

Answer (score 0):

Instead StandardCharsets.UTF_8 use StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.

Comment: Sorry Use StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1

Comment: yes i tried all the option ISO_8859_1, US_ASCII, UTF_16, UTF_16, UTF_16BE, UTF_16BE, UTF_16LE, UTF_8, but no use, getting same issue

Comment: Open your JSON File in notepad++ and change its encoding UTF-8 without BOM and then parse it java with charset UTF-8.